# algorithm for finding feature points of a face in opencv

Tags: opencv, feature-extraction

I am doing a project on expression recognition in opencv and have successfully extracted the face region,i am having trouble building my own algorithm for the feature points extraction of a face,can someone help me with it?

Comment: Your question is too vague and is unlikely to get an answer. Give more details about what you have already done and/or ask a more precise question.

Answer (score 2):

since this is my first try to answer question, I will try to do my best. I cannot post more than two links, so I will try at least to give some hints.

Your question is quite broad. It depends on the type of application and requirements. Are you doing on-line detection, is it static etc.? Based on that, you should consider keypoint detection algorithm. I do not think it is a good idea to build your own algorithm, because OpenCV already has a lot of methods that you can choose from. All you have to do in most cases is to do some pre-processing, but it depends as well.

Most popular feature detection methods are: SURF ([Opencv SURF](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_surf_intro/py_surf_intro.html)), SIFT, ORB, FAST etc. Keep in mind that SURF and SIFT ar non-free. SURF and SIFT brings a lot of features and are quite accurate, somewhat scale and rotation invariant, but also a bit slow (especially on online tracking). FAST and ORB are fast, but they are more sensitive to noise and have their own disadvantages (see descriptions on OpenCV documentation). If I were you, I would try most of them and see which one does the best job (it is not difficult to test them).

Secondly, you have to choose descriptors. Very goog introduction is here: 
[Descriptors tutorial](http://gilscvblog.wordpress.com/2013/08/26/tutorial-on-binary-descriptors-part-1/). There you will find all basic info. It is important to say, that you can mix various keypoint detection algorithms and feature description algorithms (but keep in mind that not all are compatible, tutorial will explain this).

I am out of links for this post, but OpenCV documentation provides a lot of sample code for this problem, so go ahead and have a look.

Hope you succeed. Good luck.